# Two Copies of the Same Drive

Tags: mac, hard-drive, disk-utility

I have a Western Digital 1 TB My Passport external hard drive and when I look in Disk Utility, I see two copies of the same drive - one that is uninitialized and one that is the one that's supposed to be there.

[image]

I've tried everything I can think of from erasing the ghost partition (which it says "Cannot write to the last block of the device". Duh, I ejected the drive.) to going into bash and using a whole host of diskutil commands to try and remediate the issue, no luck.

I appreciate any help I may gain on this issue, and have attached some pictures to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: Are you able to get information about each? The BSD name should correlate with what `diskutil list` shows at the command line to know if the firmware is faking out a second layer or WD is exposing an encrypted inner volume rather than the raw storage.

Comment: Well, the issue is that the drive is unformatted. diskutil list, from my knowledge, shows you the names of a volume. That won't help because it's uninitiated, it's just a plain device. It's actually showing up as a second bus device, rather than another layer or volume inside the one device. Here's the diskutil list printout - https://pastebin.com/PPy10rny / Here is the printout using "diskutil info disk2" - https://pastebin.com/QkSEmP0K